# Python FTP Upload calling variable

Tags: python, ftp, raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I'm uploading a file to the ftp server, the actual settings for the upload are correct but it isn't uploading the correct filename, it is uploading filename as the actual name of the file instead of capture......

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
#     Lightweight Motion Detection using python picamera libraries
#        based on code from raspberry pi forum by user utpalc
#        modified by Claude Pageau for this working example
#     ------------------------------------------------------------
# original code on github https://github.com/pageauc/picamera-motion

# This is sample code that can be used for further development

verbose = True
if verbose:
    print "Loading python libraries ....."
else:
    print "verbose output has been disabled verbose=False"

import picamera
import picamera.array
import datetime
import time
import ftplib
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
from fractions import Fraction

#Constants
SECONDS2MICRO = 1000000  # Constant for converting Shutter Speed in Seconds to Microseconds

# User Customizable Settings
imageDir = "images"
imagePath = "/home/pi/pimotion/" + imageDir
imageNamePrefix = 'capture-'  # Prefix for all image file names. Eg front-
imageWidth = 1980
imageHeight = 1080
imageVFlip = False   # Flip image Vertically
imageHFlip = False   # Flip image Horizontally
imagePreview = False

numberSequence = False

threshold = 10  # How Much pixel changes
sensitivity = 100  # How many pixels change

nightISO = 800
nightShutSpeed = 6 * SECONDS2MICRO  # seconds times conversion to microseconds constant

# Advanced Settings not normally changed 
testWidth = 100
testHeight = 75

def checkImagePath(imagedir):
    # Find the path of this python script and set some global variables
    mypath=os.path.abspath(__file__)
    baseDir=mypath[0:mypath.rfind("/")+1]
    baseFileName=mypath[mypath.rfind("/")+1:mypath.rfind(".")]

    # Setup imagePath and create folder if it Does Not Exist.
    imagePath = baseDir + imagedir  # Where to save the images
    # if imagePath does not exist create the folder
    if not os.path.isdir(imagePath):
        if verbose:
            print "%s - Image Storage folder not found." % (progName)
            print "%s - Creating image storage folder %s " % (progName, imagePath)
        os.makedirs(imagePath)
    return imagePath

def takeDayImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, filename):
    if verbose:
        print "takeDayImage - Working ....."
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (imageWidth, imageHeight) 
        # camera.rotation = cameraRotate #Note use imageVFlip and imageHFlip variables
        if imagePreview:
            camera.start_preview()
        camera.vflip = imageVFlip
        camera.hflip = imageHFlip
        # Day Automatic Mode
        camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
        camera.awb_mode = 'auto'
        camera.capture(filename)
    sftp = ftplib.FTP('ftpdomainname','myftpusername','myftppassword') # Connect
        fp = open(filename) # file to send
        sftp.storbinary('STOR filename', fp) # Send the file

        fp.close() # Close file and FTP
        sftp.quit()
        if verbose:  
        print "takeDayImage - Captured %s" % (filename)
    return filename

def takeNightImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, filename):
    if verbose:
        print "takeNightImage - Working ....."
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (imageWidth, imageHeight) 
        if imagePreview:
            camera.start_preview()
        camera.vflip = imageVFlip
        camera.hflip = imageHFlip
        # Night time low light settings have long exposure times 
        # Settings for Low Light Conditions 
        # Set a frame rate of 1/6 fps, then set shutter
        # speed to 6s and ISO to approx 800 per nightISO variable
        camera.framerate = Fraction(1, 6)
        camera.shutter_speed = nightShutSpeed
        camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
        camera.iso = nightISO
        # Give the camera a good long time to measure AWB
        # (you may wish to use fixed AWB instead)
        time.sleep(10)
        camera.capture(filename)
    if verbose:  
        print "checkNightMode - Captured %s" % (filename)
    return filename

def takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        time.sleep(1)
        camera.resolution = (width, height)
        with picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera) as stream:
            if daymode:
                camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
                camera.awb_mode = 'auto' 
            else:
                # Take Low Light image            
                # Set a framerate of 1/6 fps, then set shutter
                # speed to 6s and ISO to 800
                camera.framerate = Fraction(1, 6)
                camera.shutter_speed = nightShutSpeed
                camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
                camera.iso = nightISO
                # Give the camera a good long time to measure AWB
                # (you may wish to use fixed AWB instead)
                time.sleep( 10 )
            camera.capture(stream, format='rgb')
            return stream.array

def scanIfDay(width, height, daymode):
    data1 = takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode)
    while not motionFound:
        data2 = takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode)
        pCnt = 0L;
        diffCount = 0L;
        for w in range(0, width):
            for h in range(0, height):
                # get the diff of the pixel. Conversion to int
                # is required to avoid unsigned short overflow.
                diff = abs(int(data1[h][w][1]) - int(data2[h][w][1]))
                if  diff > threshold:
                    diffCount += 1
            if diffCount > sensitivity:
                break; #break outer loop.
        if diffCount > sensitivity:
            motionFound = True
        else:
            # print "Sum of all pixels=", pxCnt
            data2 = data1              
    return motionFound

def scanMotion(width, height, daymode):
    motionFound = False
    data1 = takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode)
    while not motionFound:
        data2 = takeMotionImage(width, height, daymode)
        diffCount = 0L;
        for w in range(0, width):
            for h in range(0, height):
                # get the diff of the pixel. Conversion to int
                # is required to avoid unsigned short overflow.
                diff = abs(int(data1[h][w][1]) - int(data2[h][w][1]))
                if  diff > threshold:
                    diffCount += 1
            if diffCount > sensitivity:
                break; #break outer loop.
        if diffCount > sensitivity:
            motionFound = True
        else:
            data2 = data1              
    return motionFound

def getFileName(imagePath, imageNamePrefix, currentCount):
    rightNow = datetime.datetime.now()
    if numberSequence :
        filename = imagePath + "/" + imageNamePrefix + str(currentCount) + ".jpg"
    else:
        filename = "%s/%s%04d%02d%02d-%02d%02d%02d.jpg" % ( imagePath, imageNamePrefix ,rightNow.year, rightNow.month, rightNow.day, rightNow.hour, rightNow.minute, rightNow.second)
    return filename    

def motionDetection():
    print "Scanning for Motion threshold=%i sensitivity=%i ......"  % (threshold, sensitivity)
    isDay = True
    currentCount= 1000
    while True:
        if scanMotion(testWidth, testHeight, isDay):
            filename = getFileName(imagePath, imageNamePrefix, currentCount)
            if numberSequence:
                currentCount += 1
            if isDay:
                takeDayImage( imageWidth, imageHeight, filename )
            else:
                takeNightImage( imageWidth, imageHeight, filename )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        motionDetection()
    finally:
        print ""
        print "+++++++++++++++"
        print "Exiting Program"
        print "+++++++++++++++" 
        print ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `'STOR filename'`, use the actual name of the file

`sftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, fp)`

Comment: Just tried, it takes the photo then the script crashes

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "picamera-motion.py", line 206, in <module>
    motionDetection()
  File "picamera-motion.py", line 200, in motionDetection
    takeDayImage( imageWidth, imageHeight, filename )
  File "picamera-motion.py", line 84, in takeDayImage
    sftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, fp)  # Send the file
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 471, in storbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 339, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 553 Can't open that file: No such file or directory

Comment: That's a permission issue on your ftp server, your ftp user is unable to create a file in the given directory.

Comment: Do you know how i can easily fix this permission issue?

Comment: Most common is your user does not have write permissions on the directory you are uploading to. Use the same credentials on a different ftp client and if you are getting the same error, change the permission on the upload directory which depends on server's config

Comment: I just tried uploading a file to the ftp server using a ftp client on my PC. Worked fine, the only thing is that i had to enter the port of port 21 and this isnt on my script. Could this be my issue?

Comment: No it shouldn't be as 21 is the default port. You should try to debug this from the python interpreter, only run the connect and storbinary functions to isolate the problem.